# Check variable against a certain line. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game with Python 3. I need to and see if the username and password the player enters is correct. The username and password is in a file, they are put there after the user signs up.

```
def login_signup():

    loginsignup = input("Do you want to login or sign up? Enter L/S: ")

    if loginsignup == "S":  

        userpassA = open("USERPASS.txt.txt", "a")

        user = input("Please enter a username: ")
        password = input("Please enter a password: ")

        userpassA.write(user)
        userpassA.write("\n")
        userpassA.write(password)
        userpassA.close()

    if loginsignup == "L":  # Here is where it needs to be.

        userpassR = open("USERPASS.txt.txt", "r")
        lines = userpassR.readline()

        username = input("Username: ")
        # passwordl = input("Password: ")

        if username == lines[0]:
            print("Right.")

        userpassR.close()
```

Comment: What is the question here? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: I am not sure this is the best way to do this, unless you will make the file names unique.  Also is the file name really `USERPASS.txt.txt` my guess is you have an extra `.txt`.  You could loop over the file and if the first value doesn't match what the user has enter kill the program.  I am unsure but

Comment: It just ends the program, and never says if the username and password is right or not. No error.

Comment: I can't believe nobody else has mentioned this yet-  writing a plaintext password to file is a massive security vulnerability. If anyone compromises your computer/server, they'll have everyone's passwords and usernames, which may be used on other sites / games. Instead, hash the passwords with a cryptographically secure hash, salt it, and store that. Then compare hashes instead of passwords.

Comment: You realize that you're not writing a newline after the password, right? So your file is going to look like `user1` then `pass1user2` then `pass2user3` and so on. Which is going to make it pretty hard to check anything.

Comment: Also, `readline()` returns one line, as a string. The fact that you call the variable `lines` doesn't change that. So `lines[0]` is the first character of that line. Which is unlikely to match the username.

Comment: And finally, if you're appending multiple usernames and passwords to the file, how do you expect to check against all of those users, instead of just the first one, without some kind of loop?

Comment: Yes, I know that is a massive security vulnerability. I just want to make the game first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call *userpassR.readline()*,  the next line in the file would be read, instead of all lines at once. Assuming the content in file 'USERPASS.txt.txt' is

```
user1
mypswd
```

, the first time you call *userpassR.readline()*, a string `'user1\n'` would be returned. And the next time you call it, the return value will be `'mypswd'`.

Therefore, to modify your code:

```
if loginsignup == "L":  # Here is where it is.

userpassR = open("USERPASS.txt.txt", "r")
line1 = userpassR.readline()      # It's only one line
line2 = userpassR.readline()      # It's another line

username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")

if username == line1[:-1]:         # I removed the '\n' at the end of line1
    print("Username Right.")

if password == line2:              # There isn't a '\n' here
    print("Password Right.")

userpassR.close()
```